# To view images in iTunes Album Artwork Cache?

Tags: itunes, album-art, macos

How can we view images stored in iTunes Album Artwork Cache?

What format are they? Is there anyway to see which Music Albums Artwork has been cached?

I have removed a bunch of music from my DB so I'd like to see which is still cached and which images are not. And maybe figure out which images can be useful.

Comment: Why do you want to view them? Just trash them if the folder gets too big.

Comment: @IronCraftMan - I'd like to view them. Is there a way?

Comment: Yes, through iTunes. The data is in a proprietary Apple format.